# How to extract value inside a dictionary inside nested list

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x, list

I am getting below error as I try to access the value for "hostname" key inside a dictionary

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

This is the content of hostnames = result.json()

```
{
    'accountId': 'act_1234',
    'contractId': 'ctr_1234',
    'groupId': 'grp_1234',
    'propertyId': 'prp_1234',
    'propertyName': 'www.property.com',
    'propertyVersion': 1,
    'etag': 'jbcas6764023nklf78354',
    'rules': {
        'name': 'default',
        'children': [{
            'name': 'Route',
            'children': [],
            'behaviors': [{
                'name': 'origin',
                'options': {
                    'originType': 'CUSTOMER',
                    'hostname': 'www.origin.com',
                    'forwardHostHeader': 'REQUEST_HOST_HEADER',
```

my code looks like this

```
#get hostnames of each property
    for (j, k) in itertools.zip_longest(propid, prodversion):
        propertyId = str(j)
        propertyVersion = str(k)    
        path= '/sample/v1/properties/{}/versions/{}/rules'.format(propertyId, propertyVersion)
        headers = {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "PAPI-Use-Prefixes": "true"
        }
        querystring = {
            "contractId": "ctr_1234",
            "groupId": str(i),
            "validateRules": "true",
            "validateMode": "full"
        }
        result = session.get(urljoin(baseurl, path), headers=headers, params=querystring, verify=False)
        hostnames = result.json()
        hostnameslist = [host['hostname'] for host in hostnames['rules']['children']['behaviors']['options']]
        print(hostnameslist)
```

my desired outcome would be a list of propertyName and its corresponding hostnames (could be multiple)

```
'properties': {
    'www.property1.com': ['www.origin1.com', 'www.origin2.com'],
    'www.property2.com': ['www.origin1.com', 'www.origin2.com']
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems that you have an array in "behaviors" value so you need to go into the array like this:

```
hostnameslist = [host['hostname'] for host in hostnames['rules']['children']['behaviors'][0]['options']]
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering, but I am getting the same error :(

Comment: this should work:
hostnameslist = [host['hostname'] for host in hostnames['rules']['children']['behaviors'][0]['options']['hostname']].
if not can you send what the output of hostname lists?

Comment: here is the output
File "loopProperties.py", line 60, in <module>
hostnameslist = [host['hostname'] for host in hostnames['rules']['children']['behaviors'][0]['options']['hostname']]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: you don't need the host['hostname']
try this: [host for host in hostnames['rules']['children']['behaviors'][0]['options']]

Comment: ok but how will it know we want the value for "hostname" key?

Comment: it takes all the values from the an array that you give

Comment: it's a shortcut for loop in python,the host is only a name for the parameter that took from the array, look at this example:
print([ i for i in range(0,5)]
it will print 0 1 2 3 4 5 because it take i as the iterator from the array
for more info look here https://blog.finxter.com/python-one-line-for-loop-a-simple-tutorial/

Comment: Hi this is what I have now  File "loopProperties.py", line 60, in <module>
    hostnameslist = [host for host in hostnames['rules']['children']['behaviors'][0]['options']]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: sorry didn't see that the value of the first "children" is also array so this should work:
hostnameslist = [host for host in hostnames['rules']['children'][0]['behaviors'][0]['options']] .